# Is there any way to display a live date or time of day using only CSS?

Tags: css, datetime, date, time

A friend of mine claims he knows how to display a variable, in this case time of day in H/M/S format as well as the date, using only CSS. He "forgot" what the code was, and thus couldn't tell me. It seems a bit hard to believe that this would be possible; but I'm curious nonetheless as to wether this can be done. Any ideas?

Comment: I think your friend is confusing CSS with javascript maybe(?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you use CSS just to define how things look. But you can do it with JS, here's a nice list of JS date and time functions:

http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm

and here are some practical examples to start you off:

http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_date_and_time.cfm
(delimit the code with `<script>` tags to make it work)

As a side note, CSS would be then used to make your calendar/clock look pretty, here's a nice example of that:

http://css-tricks.com/date-display-with-sprites/

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way...but it is technically cheating..

There are two libraries for CSS: LESS and SASS.

I haven't used them much but they basically allow you to write CSS in a sort of object oriented manner. As a consequence of that you may be able to use those libraries to get the exact time, but like I said you would have to include those libraries, thus "cheating".

LINKS:
LESS: http://lesscss.org/
SASS: http://sass-lang.com/

PS I think LESS is closer to what you'd be looking for if you went down this path.

Comment: LESS and SASS are not libraries, they are CSS preprocessors, programs you run on your computer which produce CSS. They have nothing to do with object oriented programming, they only offer macros and compile-time mixins. They can make writing some things in CSS quicker, that's it.